# Knockout binding error

Tags: javascript, text, knockout.js, binding, instagram

So i've got this gallery which loads Instagram data, sometimes the Instagram photo doesn't come with a caption and that's when it breaks, so the most logical thing to do is to check if the caption exists but it still breaks.

[Live example](http://[1]:%20http://laurensvandermaas.nl/stadstrand/)

```
<!-- ko if: $root.entries().length != 0 -->
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.entries() -->
            <!-- ko with: $root.entries()[$index()] -->
                <span data-bind="logger: typeof caption"></span>
                <figure>
                    <img src="" data-bind="attr: {src: images.low_resolution.url}"/>
                    <figcaption>
                            <a target="_blank" data-bind="text: user.username, attr: {href: 'http://instagram.com/' + user.username }"></a>
                         <!--ko if: typeof caption != 'null'-->
                            <span>
                                <!-- ko text: caption.text --><!-- /ko -->
                            </span>

                         <!--/ko-->
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: You should be able to have both the if-binding and the caption text binding in the span tag, rather than using ko pseudo-tags.
Also, the check for root.entries length is unnecessary; the foreach handles the zero case properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof` operator doesn't return `null`, so your conditional is in fact unconditional: it always tries to render `caption.text` even if `caption` is null.

You could try:

```
<!--ko if: caption-->
```

Which will expand the contents of the comment-template if `caption` is "truthy" (is not `false`, `null`, `undefined`, 0, empty string, etc.)